# Elasticsearch separating out data into indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have three different data sources which get updated at separate times each day. My first idea was to combine all the data into a single index but I'm wondering if it's more sensible to keep each data source in their own index. That way when a data source gets updated, I can just refresh one index.

When it comes to searching I'll just search all index. Is this a sensible approach or will it introduce a lot of overheads by separating it out.

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it makes sense to merge the indices you can do so, but if you want the flexibility of refreshing only one source - you should keep them separated.

I'm not sure if you're aware of [aliases](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/indices-aliases.html): you can define an alias that will include all the three indices - so that from a "user" perspective you don't have to search "all the indices" - it'll be transparent to the user that it's actually not a single index.